# How to update product price of a particular shop?

Tags: updates, prestashop-1.7, price

I have a multishop Prestahop site. In which now I want to update product price of a single shop through an external file. I tried this

```
        $productUpObj = new Product($productId,false,1,16); //BV2
        $productUpObj->shop = array(16);
        $productUpObj->id_shop_default = 16;
        $productUpObj->price = $productIncObjArr['price'];
        $productUpObj->save();
```

But it's not working. Please suggest any solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm your code looks correct. In my module i have:

```
$obj = new Product($value['id_product']);
$obj->price = (float) $value['base_price'];
if ($value['unity']) {
    $obj->unity = $value['unity'];
    $obj->unit_price = 0;
}

//multistore
if ($value['shops']) {
   //$value['shops'] have string "1,2,3"
   $obj->id_shop_list = explode(',', $value['shops']);
}
$obj->update();
```

Ohh, now i see. I have **$obj->id_shop_list** instead **$obj->shop**